# accessing objects passed down as an argument

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, arguments

```
function ngserve(props){
    console.log('hello' + props)
} 

ngserve({name: 'Trump'}) // hello [object Object];

function ng(props){
    console.log('hello', props)
}

ng({name: 'Trump'}) // hello {name : Trump}
```

---

Why can't I use concatenation to access the value and what 
        does that [object Object] mean?

Comment: `[object Object]` is the string representation of a plain object in JavaScript. When you concatenate a string with an object, the latter is coerced into a string, which gives you that representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so when you do `a+b` in javascript it tries to convert them both to `string` in your case , and `[object Object]` is just that string representation;

you can do `console.log('hello' + JSON.stringify(props))`

Answer (score 0):

You can access `name` property using `.` as `props.name` in `console.log('hello' + props)`

You can also, `ngserve('Trump')` just pass `Trump` as string

`[object Object]` is what you get when casting object to string